# (error code 28) Resolving timed out after 5000 milliseconds Ubuntu server - DNS?

Tags: ssh, apache2, php, dns, netplan

### Intent:

I am trying to load images programmatically using cUrl, into Prestashop in a XAMP via SSH.

### What I tried:

I have looked around and the issue may be on the setup of the server.

I tried to change the in the `php.ini` file the values of `max_execution_time`, `memory_limit`, `max_input_vars`, `max_input_time` but did not work.

I tried to `ping` the website where I am collecting the image:

```
ping brandsdistribution.com
PING brandsdistribution.com (109.233.123.248) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

and keeps running until I key interrupt it and it returns:

```
--- brandsdistribution.com ping statistics ---
135 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 137194ms
```

while if I `ping` google.com:

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.168.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ams16s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.168.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=56.4 ms
64 bytes from ams16s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.168.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=47.6 ms
64 bytes from ams16s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.168.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=43.7 ms
64 bytes from ams16s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.168.206): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=80.0 ms
```

```
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 43.747/56.940/80.002/14.079 ms
```

### Question

Is this a DNS issue? how can I fix it?

### Error message

```
(1/1) Exception
file_get_contents_curl failed to download https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/stock_product_image_107510_1178872247.jpg : (error code 28) Resolving timed out after 5000 milliseconds

in Tools.php line 2162
at ToolsCore::file_get_contents_curl('https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/stock_product_image_107510_1178872247.jpg', 5, null)

in Tools.php line 2235
at ToolsCore::file_get_contents('https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/stock_product_image_107510_1178872247.jpg', false, resource)

in Tools.php line 2294
at ToolsCore::copy('https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/stock_product_image_107510_1178872247.jpg', '/var/www/html/img/tmp/ps_importTmA1vB')

in productCreate.php line 107
at copyImg('68', '157', 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/stock_product_image_107510_1178872247.jpg', 'products', false)

in productCreate.php line 66
at addImage(object(Product), 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/stock_product_image_107510_1178872247.jpg', true)

in productCreate.php line 44
at createProduct(array('PRODUCT', '107510', 'Nike', 'W-ZoomGravity', 'BQ3203-006_W-ZoomGravity', '18', '101.00', '81.00', '57.00', 'Genere:Donna - Tipologia:Sneakers - Tomaia:materiale sintetico, materiale tessile - Interno:materiale sintetico, materiale tessile - Suola:gomma', '2.00', 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/stock_product_image_107510_1178872247.jpg', 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/stock_product_image_107510_2136019726.jpg', 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/prod/stock_product_image_107510_1040197763.jpg', 'Vietnam', 'Nike', '', '', '', 'Scarpe', '', 'Sneakers', '', '', 'Continuativi', 'Rosa', '', 'pink,dimgray', 'Donna', '', '', '', '', ''))
in productCreate.php line 22
```

#### Spec

- Ubuntu Server 20.04
- PHP 7.2
- mysql 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB

#### Edits:

1. my nameserver is 127.0.0.53

Comment: What are your namesevers? https://www.tecmint.com/find-my-dns-server-ip-address-in-linux/

Comment: @Idias the nameserver is 127.0.0.53

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue trying to install PrestaShop v1.7.6.7 at 14 Mar 2023 on MAMP using php v7.2.30

On top of increasing the max_execution_time I enabled the Opcache and finally worked!